# Track traffic & purchases came from instagram shop

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, tracking, woocommerce, instagram

Is there a way to track visitors and purchases for my woocommerce store that came from my instagram shop?

I know I Must Use UTM Links and see results in GA for Specific link, but I have hundreds of products in my instagram shop, must I adjust every link for every product in the cataloge or there is an easier way to do this ?